# why the absence of curly brackets after for loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am a beginner, please can u tell me why there are no curly brackets `{ }` after for loop in the program.  I've made a comment for the issue.

```
void main()
{
    int a[50],n,count_neg=0,count_pos=0,I;

    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array\n");

    for (I=0;I < n;I++)          /* i dont understand why no {} occuerred after this for loop please explain*/
        scanf("%d",&a[I]);

    for(I=0;I < n;I++)
    {
        if(a[I] < 0)
          count_neg++;
        else
         count_pos++;
    }

    printf("There are %d negative numbers in the array\n",count_neg);
    printf("There are %d positive numbers in the array\n",count_pos);
}
```

Comment: Also why you mention subject line like `count number of negative and positive number in an array`? because your problem related to for loop understanding.

Comment: Yes, that is not reflecting your actual doubt; please give appropriate title and description.

Answer (score 3):

It is allowed to not put brackets for single lines. However I would strongly advice to *not* do it. Here is [a famous bug](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2014/02/gotofail/) which can be the consequence of not using brackets.

For example if you write

```
if(test)
   foo();
```

and later need a second function call you may make the error of writing

```
if(test)
   foo();
   bar();
```

which is *not* what you want.

If you use brackets right from the beginning and write

```
if(test) {
   foo();
}
```

you do not have that issue:

```
if(test) {
   foo();
   bar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one statement that needs to be looped i.e. if the loop body is just one statement then the braces `{ }` can be omitted. This works recursively, e.g.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   for(j = 0; j < m; ++j)
      for(k = 0; k < l; ++k)
        process(v[i][j][k]);
```

is the same as

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
   for(j = 0; j < m; ++j)
   {
      for(k = 0; k < l; ++k)
      {
        process(v[i][j][k]);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code consists of one single line, you may write it without brackets.

this isn't only applicable for loops, it also works for conditional clauses like `if` `if else` or `else`

for example:

```
if(a == b){
    a++;
}
```

is the same as

```
if(a == b)
    a++;
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! :)

I did not understand your question in general but still I will tell you the following:
In programming the opening and closing brackets { } are used to identify a code block, which will be executed from the opening bracket **{ without interruption until the closing bracket }**. Code blocks are used to isolate one section of code from another.

Example 1:

```
void Function1()
{

  void Function2()
  {
    // Calculate
    // Long Stuff
    // Complicated
    // Atom Bombs exploding

  } // Close Function2

  void Function3()
  {
    // Do 
    // Some
    // Other
    // Evil
    // Stuff

  } // Close Function3

}// Close Function1

void Function3()
{

  InnerFunction(); // This will execute Function3, but without going to Function3,  
                   // because the code of Function2 is ISOLATED with {} from the code of Function3

}// Close Function2
```